# Multiprocessing BaseManager shutdown() takes twenty-seconds

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using BaseManager to share a queue with a pool of worker processes. I call start() on it in order to have the manager run in another thread.

Under shutdown(), the documentation says "This is only available if start() has been used to start the server process." However, if I call shutdown(), the foreground process will block on the manager process for twenty-seconds before terminating, every time. If I don't call shutdown(), the foreground process leaves immediately?

What am I missing?

Also, does anyone have any idea why the documentation says, "This can be called multiple times."? Why would you send multiple shutdown signals to the manager process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it waits for 20 Seconds by design. Please [refer here](http://fossies.org/dox/Python-2.7.3/managers_8py_source.html)  for more info

```
        process.join(timeout=0.2)
        if process.is_alive():
            util.info('manager still alive')
            if hasattr(process, 'terminate'):
                util.info('trying to `terminate()` manager process')
                process.terminate()
                process.join(timeout=0.1)
                if process.is_alive():
                    util.info('manager still alive after terminate')
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the shutdown call or the creation of the process that indicates a delay. What makes you think that it's by design? When I don't call shutdown(), no processes seem to be left open. I question the significance of even having the call.

Comment: The shutdown calls `util._run_finalizers(0)` to run the finalizers that have been declared for the start process. Now if you were to refer to defination of start you will notice that there is registration of finalizers which calls `_finalize_manager`  which has a  timeout parameter used when waiting for manager to shutdown cleanly before resorting to terminate()